# Synonym from DBpedia is getting unnecessary links

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

The below query having 2 problem :
- Getting additional link for me in synonym, I want to just show the detail as coming in the page - http://dbpedia.org/page/Shortness_of_breath
- Showing field as a link rather than text.

```
SELECT   ?abstract ?icd10 ?icd9 ?icd ?field ?synonyms
WHERE    
{ 
VALUES ?name { 'Shortness of breath'@en } ?s rdfs:label ?name; dbo:abstract ?abstract 
FILTER   langMatches(lang(?abstract),'en') 
FILTER   langMatches(lang(?name),'en') 
OPTIONAL {?s dbo:icd10 ?icd10 } 
OPTIONAL {?s dbo:icd9 ?icd9 } 
OPTIONAL {?s dbo:icd ?icd } 
OPTIONAL {?s dbp:field ?field } 
OPTIONAL {?s dbp:synonyms ?synonyms } 
}
```

[image]

Comment: You want to have what? The Wikipedia redirects? then replace `OPTIONAL {?s dbp:synonyms ?synonyms } ` by `OPTIONAL {?synonyms dbo:wikiPageRedirects ?s }` - or if you want to have both, use a `UNION` inside the `OPTIONAL` pattern with both triple patterns.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AKSW . If i use WikiPage redirect, it is giving all the urls, basically my result above is good, but I dont  need that `<http://w3.org>` part. I just need synonym string.

Comment: ah ok. what you want is the lexical form of the literal, done via `str` function in SPARQL: `SELECT   ?abstract ?icd10 ?icd9 ?icd ?field (str(?synonyms) as ?synonyms_txt) ...`